# CORS error appears with the same source code by using different build servers

Tags: java, maven, cors, bamboo, rhel8

We have Java 17 app, which is configured correctly to not have CORS error.
After Bamboo builds server migrated from RHEL 7 to RHEL 8 we noticed that generated jar is different by size (with same source code and build scripts: Maven) and that it started generated CORS errors when called from UI.
I am curious, as I never saw such thing - what config on build server itself can cause such thing?